# Can anyone provide me with a working example of ubuntu-cloud-init.cfg for an Impish kvm/qemu host?

Tags: virtualization, qemu, cloud-init

I've been pulling my hair out for two days trying to get a working cloud init config for 21.10 guest VMs on a 21.10 host.
The problem is authentication.
No user can authenticate to the VM using virsh console. Attempts to ssh into the guest VM are rejected with "permission denied."
I'd settle for getting ttyS0 console login working.

Here's my cloud-init.yaml

```
users:
  - default
  - name: muh
    groups: [users, adm, sudo]
    primary_group: msh
    lock_passwd: false
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    home: /home/muh
    shell: /bin/bash
    passwd: $6$rounds=4096$eaJbaLFRPeA.OA1J$nwGXJgDzreIiKgZSEvf3QU58SMoN/Hh5pno3L9.Ww/qhWOcDANz0ot8Yp3fIZob/sV1yzdO/xbGMuXH7QyPsB/

packages: 
  - qemu-guest-agent 
  - tmux 

final_message: "Up after $UPTIME"
```

Here are the actions I take to set up the seed iso and target qcow2 image.

```
create -f qcow2 -b /var/iso/impish-server-cloudimg-amd64.img /var/kvm/kube4.qcow2 40G
```

> qemu-img: warning: Deprecated use of backing file without explicit
> backing format (detected format of qcow2) Formatting
> '/var/kvm/kube4.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 cluster_size=65536 extended_l2=off
> compression_type=zlib size=42949672960
> backing_file=/var/iso/impish-server-cloudimg-amd64.img
> backing_fmt=qcow2 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16

```
cloud-localds -v --network-config=/srv/init/ubuntu-network-init.cfg /var/kvm/kube4-seed.img /srv/init/ubuntu-cloud-init.cfg
```

> wrote /var/kvm/kube4-seed.img with filesystem=iso9660 and
> diskformat=raw

Here is my virt-install syntax.

```
virt-install --name kube4 \
  --virt-type kvm --memory 4096 --vcpus 2 \
  --boot hd,menu=on \
  --disk path=/var/kvm/kube4-seed.img,device=cdrom \
  --disk path=/var/kvm/kube4.qcow2,device=disk \
  --os-type Linux \
  --os-variant ubuntu20.04 \
  --network bridge=br0 \
  --console pty,target_type=serial \
  --noautoconsole
```

If I mount the VM's disk, I see that my "custom" user and the ubuntu user is locked.

```
muh:!:19109:0:99999:7:::
ubuntu:!:19109:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: I'm using Daily Build [20220419] impish-server-cloudimg-amd64.img

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
#cloud-config
groups:
  - admingroup: [root,sys,muh]
  - cloud-users
users:
  - default:
  - name: muh
    hashed_passwd: $6$rounds=4096$yHtXbsaPlIvgAUgE$frghQYnGgYCklXspnl.j13uhf1UHptZ1V74n5eHvH4QBeAlMZn38C/APVb.7/wi/WBmeipgEVd.APscjqpCa//
    shell: /bin/bash
    home: /home/muh
    lock-passwd: false
    ssh_pwauth: true
    chpasswd: {expire: false}
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: sudo, adm, admin
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDF1lV7RYWz88LXvthQA4Z/9YUhiRKMr+RWtBd3K6PaSEQoZh6fAxev1mDywR51NX216gjKETP+zuVuwKPWhFMTxe2l4DO68XWC86Agt+YeCjwyIbtzZqjjkD1Oz/cpEi+GQGXY3tvkGMasx9GHqgBnv2KimMZQH9CoHSOqmgoWBvsWmxUG12lBEZZMcM/vLmsD9Eo1sYmEMW4/CPiREC2h6MAx3s+XFxjLjD6CrDTSJAy5B59oXw25Z+fWdlwAJaUpY2qiWhgp4Vbc2L/DEZtp4QJMXrIlIfba3yMPdjXr8loEn73xZ4PXb0WUmDxdko/Vvs/LzrEAupbv6kIjPFA5 muh@fnordic
```